# Creating distinct buttons in a loop in Python/Kivy?

Tags: python, button, bluetooth, kivy

I've built a simple program that scans for Bluetooth devices and displays their name/address on buttons.  Code:

```
def discover(self, *args):
    devList = discover_devices() 
    for device in devList: 
        name = str(lookup_name(device))
        if str(lookup_name(device)) == "":  
            name = "Unknown device" 
        deviceinfo = "[color=1f358e][font=tahoma]Device name: [color=1f358e][font=tahoma]" + str(name) + "\n[color=1f358e][font=tahoma]MAC address: [color=1f358e][font=tahoma]" + str(device) 
        btnDevice = Button(text=deviceinfo, markup = True, font_size='17sp')
        btnDevice.bind(on_release=self.optionmenu)  
        box.add_widget(btnDevice) 


    self.boxes.add_widget(box)
    layout.clear_widgets() 

def optionmenu(self, *args): 
    print name
```

So, basically, I want to A.) Discover Bluetooth devices and add them to devList, B.) Create a button displaying the device name/address for each device in devList, C.) Allow for the user to click on a button and print the name of the device that button is assigned to.  I am sure there has to be some significant structural change in that part of the code for this to work, but I can't figure out exactly what.

Comment: You can replace `name = ... ; if str(lookup... : name = ...` with `name = lookup_name(device) or 'Unknown device'`, by the way.

Comment: And have you tried `on_release=lambda x=name: self.optionmenu(name)` with `def optionmenu(self, name): print name`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yeah, clicking on any button returns the same name, I'm guessing the last one it found.

Comment: Sorry; that should be `...optionmenu(x)`, not `..optionmenu(name)`. Try that.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Okay I think we are getting somewhere.  It seems to be printing the name of the button itself (kivy.uix.button.button object at....), but it IS doing separate names for each button. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be doing that. Did you change the definition for `optionmenu` as suggested above?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yeah, I believe so.  Maybe you can [find](http://prntscr.com/aug0a4) an error but I think I tried everything you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick.

```
def discover(self, *args):
    devList = discover_devices() 
    for device in devList: 
        name = str(lookup_name(device))
        if str(lookup_name(device)) == "":  
            name = "Unknown device" 
        deviceinfo = "[color=1f358e][font=tahoma]Device name: [color=1f358e][font=tahoma]" + str(name) + "\n[color=1f358e][font=tahoma]MAC address: [color=1f358e][font=tahoma]" + str(device) 
        btnDevice = Button(text=deviceinfo, markup = True, font_size='17sp')
        btnDevice.bind(on_release=self.optionmenu)  
        box.add_widget(btnDevice) 


    self.boxes.add_widget(box)
    layout.clear_widgets()

def optionmenu(self, instance): 
    print instance.text
```

"Instance" simply means the button object you pressed on. You can change this to whatever you like of course.